# Do I need a callback in this loop?

Tags: javascript, xml, loops, foreach, callback

I'm successfully searching & replacing content in an xml and then importing the xml for a single instance but when I try to introduce an array it fails. I'm thinking that it is trying to import the xml before it is done modifying it. Do I need a callback for this and if so can I get some help structuring the callback? - I am having trouble wrapping my head around callbacks.

```js
$('#btn-version_sot').on('click', function(){
    csInterface.evalScript('exportXML('+ JSON.stringify(profile_sot.xmlDirectory) +')',
        function(result){

            profile_sot.targetXml = result;

            let currentShow = 'show1';
            let shows = ['show2', 'show3', 'show4'];

            shows.forEach(function(show, index, array) {
            
                let currentValue1 = new RegExp('<name>'+ currentShow + '<\/name>', 'g');
                let newValue1 = '<name>'+ show + '</name>';

                const res = fs.readFileSync(profile_sot.targetXml, 'utf-8')
                    .replace(currentValue1, newValue1)

                fs.writeFile(profile_sot.targetXml, res, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                    if (err){
                        alert(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        currentShow = show;
                        importXML();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    );
});


function importXML(){
    csInterface.evalScript('importXML('+ JSON.stringify(profile_sot.targetXml) +')',
        function(result){
            if(result){
                // alert(result);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: All of those iterations are trying to write to the same `profile_sot.targetXml` file, is that really what you want?

Comment: What is `fs`? Doesn't look like node.js if you are using jQuery event handlers in the same code.

Comment: I'm iterating to the same xml and importing each time. In essence it imports different data each time.

Comment: Is it bad practice to use jquery and node fs together?

Comment: No, it's just that it doesn't work? In which environment are you running this code, in the browser?

Comment: Here is a link to node fs:  https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/fs/

Comment: It works if I only cycle through once. It's when I loop over multiple iterations that it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm running this code in Adobe Premiere.

Comment: And adobe premiere has both a DOM as well as node implementation in the same environment? Cool, can you link the docs of that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179838/discussion-between-sbaden-and-bergi).

Comment: victorianece.com/2015/12/…
github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/…